# Hide Button in ListBox Item using DataTrigger in WPF ListBox Based on Count

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate, datatrigger

I'm having a `ListBox`, in that `ItemTemplate` I'm having one `TextBlock` and one Delete `Button`.

**My Requirement**: If the `ObservableCollection<string> Person` has only one record, then I need to hide the Delete `Button`. If more than one record is there then I need to show Delete `Button` for all the Item.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Person, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Transparent"  Margin="0 10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Contact, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <Button  Grid.Row="1" Content="X" Foreground="Red" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

DataTrigger:

```
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
```

Kindly assist me how to set `DataTrigger` for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTrigger could be in the Button's Style:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                             Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```